# Finding the longest Common Subsequence from a table

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have two input strings for the LCS problem:
1: ABCDGH
2:AEDFHR

The following table represents the Dynamic Programming Solution to the bottom-up table for the length of the LCS:

[image]

Based on the method provided in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnD96abizww&list=PLrmLmBdmIlpsHaNTPP_jHHDx_os9ItYXr), when trying to find the actual letters in the LCS, you start from the end of the table and go backwards. If the cells to the left and right aren't the same as the current one and the cell diagonal is one less, then you know the character in the current column is included and you move back diagonally. Otherwise you either move to the left or the right.

Following that approach, you would have this sequence of movements (H,R), (H,H),and then to (F,G). But once you get there, how would the algorithm decide where to go next? It seems that it should go left as that would lead to 'D' being included in the LCS from the next column to the left, but the cells to the left, right, and diagonal of (F,G) all have values of 2 and the cell to the diagonal isn't one less. **So what should the logic in the algorithm be in cases where you have a cell surrounded by the same value?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic programming problems often have multiple optimal solutions. When two or three adjacent cells have the same value, they are equally good, and if that value is also the best one among the adjacent cells, jumping to either one of them will lead to one of the optimal solutions. (Note that your problem statement might impose additional constraints, such as "if there are multiple optimal solutions, pick the one where the last substitution is as early as possible".)